# tvOS - dismissing to top of storyboard causes all intermediate screens to -viewWillAppear/Disappear

Tags: objective-c, uistoryboard, tvos

I am several levels deep in a storyboard and want to unroll everything all the way back to the first screen. Fortunately, there are APIs designed to do exactly this:

```
UIViewController *topController = [UIApplication sharedApplication].keyWindow.rootViewController;
[topController dismissViewControllerAnimated:NO completion:nil];
```

However, this method seems to "unroll" the view stack one by one, causing each view between my current position and the first screen to briefly invoke `viewWillAppear`, `viewDidAppear`, `viewWillDisappear`, and `viewDidDisappear`. This causes a cacophony of activity in my app, as most of the intermediate screens do interesting things when they appear. I can set breakpoints in Xcode and watch these methods get invoked in reverse order back to the main screen.

I need a way to pop back to the start of the storyboard without causing every screen along the path to light up and do work.

If this means I cannot use `viewWillAppear` for this purpose any more, I am willing to switch to a replacement method as long as one exists.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is expected behaviour. I assume you're presenting the layers of views with `presentViewController...` calls on each previous view.

You should look at using a `UINavigationController` as your top level view instead. Then you can just call `popToRootViewControllerAnimated:` when you want to go all the way back.

Comment: I'm having a hard time finding tvOS examples which do this. The iOS examples generally involve things like tapping on a table view which aren't relevant to me at all. Care to point me in the right direction?

Comment: Also, `dismissViewControllerAnimated` allows me to go up several levels without necessarily going to the *root*. In many cases I'm not going all the way up. How would I do this with a nav controller? Unwind segues everywhere? Those are kinda crummy.

Comment: `UINavigationController` also has a `popToViewController:animated:` method that lets you jump up the stack to any position you like. Once you set up the nav controller, use `pushViewController:animated:` to present a VC, and `popViewController:animated:` to dismiss a single VC. Add in `popToViewController:animated:` when you want to go back more than one level, and `popToRootViewControllerAnimated:` when you want to go back to the start. Look at the `viewControllers` property of the nav controller to see the full stack of view controllers your nav controller is managing.

Comment: So this didn't work for me at first because it turns out I was using programmatic storyboard segues via `[self performSegueWithIdentifier: @"MySegue" sender: self]` not realizing this was taking my UINavigationController out of the equation entirely. I ripped all of the existing segues out (even from the storyboard) and replaced them with `pushViewController` and `popViewController` and things are 100% better now. My flow didn't lend itself to segues anyway (it was a spiderweb!) so it's a win-win for me.